# How to make p:menu scrollable in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, menu, scroll, scrollable

I have a menu which I fill programmatically with a model. But I want it to become **scrollable** when its items become **too many** to be displayed in the page.

Here is my menu:

```
<p:menu overlay="true" trigger="imgNotif" my="left top"
at="bottom left" model="#{notifController.model}" />
```

Is there a way to make it scrollable (programmatically or using its style/attributes)?

Thank you

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16194&sid=7484a1d1e659b09e7da023cf8d17ced7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```css
.ui-menu {
  overflow-y: scroll;      
  height: 200px;      
}
```

Comment: This answer needs an update: `p-menu-list` is now the class that needs to be modified, not `ui-menu`. I also found it better to set `max-height` rather than `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code to make menu scrollable

```
<p:tabView scrollable="true">
            <p:tab title="MenuHeader">menu content</p:tab>
            <p:tab title="MenuHeader">menu content</p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but now and using primefaces 11, I did it using this css:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-parent .ui-menu-child{
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 80vh;
}
```

This way, your submenu list will grow to a max of 80% of the screen if it passes this value it will make scrollable.